# WooCommerce личный кабинет, нету стилей. Как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ниже показал как выглядит почему-то личный кабинет, не понимаю почему.
[image]

Comment: Научись пользоваться инструментами вебмастера в браузере и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: [Легко](http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20firefox)!

Comment: Эпично. Я понимаю, это по сути в любом браузере есть, я пользуюсь хромом. Но это не даёт мне ответ.

Comment: Вот, я тут https://qna.habr.com/q/794213 много чего писал (откройте комментарии). Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не смог разобраться до конца, в чём была проблема. Просто не было нужных стилей, по этому писал их сам в style.css and woocommerce.css.

Я думаю, что это единственный вариант. Скорее всего была проблема из-за самой темы.